# Unhide objects/legends in Dashboard tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have objects on the dashboards - filters and legends, I've click 'x' on some of the objects because I dont want to display them. Now I want to display them - how can I make them appear on the dashboard again? I've tried remove and add the sheet again, but doesn't bring back everything anymore.

gemmo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When editing your dashboard, select the sheet or object that you wish to manipulate. You should see a small black triangle in the top right corner of the sheet. Pressing on that triangle reveals a menu that allows you to control it's settings -- including which filters and legends are displayed.

Once you've turned on displaying a filter or legend, you can move it where you like, edit its title or format, or change it between tiled and floating to adjust its position.

Answer (score 2):

To unhide Legends, Follow steps as under in the image:
[image]

Select floating and adjust Legends as per your requirement and you will get desired results.